# Why does ActionScript String replace with curly brackets not work?

Tags: string, actionscript, replace, curly-brackets

```
trace("A {0} C".replace("{0}","B"));
```

Does not work.

```
trace("A %0 C".replace("%0","B"));
```

Does work.

What's so special about { } curly brackets that they can not be replaced? Escaping also does not work. Anyway to get it to work?

Comment: you have to espace the { with \{

Comment: Both of them works and gives A B C as the result, what the problem?
http://wonderfl.net/c/56iZ